# I need to reset my old iPad, but forgot restrictions passcode and don't have an iTunes backup

Tags: ipad, security

I found an old iPad 2 generation (what I don't use anymore) and wish to gift it to my parents.

A lot of personal data on this iPad.

I need to reset my old iPad, but forgot restrictions passcode and don't have an iTunes backup before restrictions passcode.

Howto reset iPad with factory settings?

Answer (score 1):

Within iTunes make a manual backup of the old iPad.  Once that is in place you can follow the steps outlined at this [blog post](http://www.simonblog.com/2011/03/16/how-to-recover-forgotten-iphone-restrictions-passcode/)...at least if you are working with iOS 6.

For iOS 7 or 8, follow the steps outlined at [my blog post](http://excentrix.io/recover-your-ios-78-restrictions-passcode-forgotten-or-otherwise/) on how to actually retrieve or recover your passcode without resetting to factory defaults.

Comment: Blog links are both dead. As at 2022 There is no way to just bypass the code & there is no way to recover other than to a backup made *before* the restriction code was added.